# Reducing ambiguity about something standing horizontally, right side up

Tags: phrase-requests

A small remote controlled car can be hooked up with a cable to a computer, where various configurations can be altered. There is an option to re-calibrate some sensors. For it to work accurately, the vehicle has to stand horizontally, on its wheels.

We put up a warning **"the vehicle has to stand horizontally!"**. Yet we later noticed that some users interpreted it literally, and put it on its back (technically, it's still laying horizontally, just upside down), because it's easier to access the cables in that position.

I'm considering adding "right side up", but I'm worried many non-native speakers would think that the right side of the vehicle should point upwards, and would lay it on its side. Just specifying "on its wheels" might lead to it being placed on a slanted surface.

Writing a longer explanation risks the warning being overlooked and not being read at all.

Is there a short and more unambiguous way to express this requirement?

Comment: To calibrate, set the car on its wheels on a level surface.

Comment: What is this "laying" thing and what is it that it's laying? Is it a chicken?

Comment: @tchrist : 1. The very first definition of that verb in the first dictionary I stumbled upon is *"To place down in a position of rest, or in a horizontal position."* 2. It was not even part of the discussed terminology or the original wording I wanted to change, it was only part of a side comment. 3. How did you even become a moderator with this kind of an attitude? Is this the new standard we should follow on this site?

Comment: I'm sorry that you did not see the humor intended. When you **lay** something on its side, that thing is **lying** horizontally. It is not laying; **you** are laying. It is merely lying. That's because transitive uses and intransitive uses demand different verbs altogether. This is the same as when you **raise** something up, it is not raising, **you** are. It is merely **rising**. Do you understand the difference yet?  The "A" versions  (*to lay* and *to raise*) take obligatory objects which must not be omitted; the "I" versions (*to lie* and *to rise*) forbid objects. You used the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

Place the car **upright**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upright) defines *upright* as "vertically upward". (Although it's not always easy to define directions in a dictionary.)

You can see examples with pictures online on wikihow.com, for instance on their page "[3 Ways to Slice an Apple](https://www.wikihow.life/Slice-an-Apple)", which starts "Place the apple upright on a cutting board", accompanied by a picture of the apple, stalk upwards. Similarly "[3 Ways to Store Vodka](https://www.wikihow.com/Store-Vodka)" has pictures of upright bottles, with the neck upwards and the base on a shelf.

It is similar to "right side up" but is less ambiguous because it doesn't feature the phrase "right side" with the ambiguous word "side".